# catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove does not remove Image from the disk in Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, media-images

This is how we update **product photos** via **SOAP sequence**:

- `catalogProductAttributeMediaList`
- `catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove`
- `catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate`

By calling SOAP `catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove` Magento does not remove photos from the disk/db .

The deleted photo still can be accessible by url for example:
www.example.com/media/catalog/product/P/A/PAexample.jpg

Also after calling `catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate` the photo name is changed automatically by Magento to PAexample_1.jpg 
and then PAexample_2.jpg ..... in subsequent photo updates (SOAP sequence).

And we can not have the same file name after product photo updates.

Wondering what could be best work around?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how the code works in magento, it appears that *is* default expected functionality.   Think of it like this...

Someone shares a link to to your product on facebook, or whatever.  That website now knows that www.yourstore.com/media/catalog/hugeurl/cachewhatever.jpg exists as a representation of that product.

Months later, you go in and delete the image because you have a better bigger higher resolution image.  In your mind, you'd think "hey, I want all those links out there in the world to update", but in reality magento thinks "those people out there have expected this image to be like *this* with these dimensions". I can only speculate, but the point is to prevent broken links images unexpectedly turning into other images.

Magento doesn't delete the file, but it just creates an addtional file by appending the _integer.jpg to it.  I confirmed using a debugger that this is how it works.

I'm revising my product sync software because right now I delete images and recreate them any time a product needs to sync but in reality, I need to compare the hash from my new image and the old one and only delete and recreate the image if it has actually changed.

Additionally, for a code related answer, there are only references to create Varien_Io_File objects in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php.`   Look there for more answers to how the process works.  You won't find any references to delete files.